# Does node.js provide a way to write non-trivial clean URLs?

Tags: node.js, clean-urls

I would like to write non-trivial dynamic clean URLs in node.js. For example

```
mynodeserver.com/browse/itemid
```

instead of

```
mynodeserver.com/browse?id=itemid
```

Right now my static clean urls (browse,login,register,etc) are based on string comparison, which obviously is not the complete solution for this problem.

```
var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
//check if there is a request handler for this path
if (typeof handle[ pathname ] === 'function') 
{
    handle[pathname]( response, request, postData );
}
```

Is there a native way (or light plugin) to write non-trivial clean URLs?

I'm using Cloud9 IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing your own parser for urls should not be a difficult job I think. Assuming you know how to use regular expressions.

I've never heard about standalone plugin for doing this, but you can use very good [Express framework](http://expressjs.com/). It has url parser built-in.

Comment: you were right, I was able to pull it off with some RegExp magic and tricks.

Comment: @supertopi can you provide the code that you used to get the clean urls working?? Is is possible to have two levels of path like xyz.com/tag/football/1, xyz.com/tag/cricket/2 where cricket and football are tag names and 1 and 2 are page numbers.

Comment: @peter hey, it's been a long time since I wrote this parser. Here's some of the code, you may or may not find it useful. http://pastebin.com/RTUMt0cr